# Comparing date and time and the same time in perl

Tags: perl, date, compare

I want to compare both date and time check if the timestamp from the file I'm going to open will have equal or greater date and time as if the my timestamp which looks like this:

```
$Date = "20170608";
$Time = "105006";
```

My main problem is how to do it efficiently possibly without adding perl libraries and how to check it when there's going to be situation of date switching and the hour will be for example 23:59:44

Comment: is that time 1:05:06?

Comment: Yes, my mistake

Comment: *"without adding perl libraries"* Why are you restricting yourself to only 5% of the power of Perl?

Comment: Any suggestions with libraries ?

Comment: Re "*without adding perl libraries*", Perl basically only comes with what's needed to install modules. The rest is mostly there for historical reasons. It's kinda silly to restrict yourself to that!

Answer (score 2):

`Time::Piece` is core in perl, and supports 'strptime'.

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl

use strict;
use warnings;
use Time::Piece;

my $Date = "20170608";
my $Time = "10506";

my $ts = Time::Piece->strptime( "$Date $Time", "%Y%m%d %H%M%S" );
print $ts, "\n";

print "Delta:", $ts->epoch - time(), "\n";
```

Was unclear on what time that `$Time` represented - `strptime` converts it to 10:50:06, but I'm guessing it might be intended to be 01:05:06?

If so, then zero pad.

```
$Time = sprintf ( "%06d", $Time );
```

To read the timestamp from the file metadata, then you need `stat`:

```
my $mtime = (stat $filename)[9];
```

Comment: It suppose to be 10:50:06

The problem is that I'm not going to compare it with current time but with date which is saved as a variable. And the problem is that the time may be wrong - it will turned to 00:00:00 after 12pm and then I'll have to check the date somehow

Comment: Checking if a time is today or yesterday is probably easier than you think - convert it, assuming it's today - then look at the size of the time delta. If it's >1d, then chances are it's the wrong date. I can't go into more detail though, without knowing your time comparison.

Comment: $DataStart = "20170608";
  $TimeStart = "235806";
  
  $DatetoCompare = "20170609";
  $TimetoCompare = "000106";